# 'sandboxing' user defined python function

Tags: python

I'm looking to allow users to define their own functions for use in a program, however, I don't want them to break things - ideally I would like to restrict this to core language functions, maybe the `math` module

The custom function would be something like this (defined in, say user_function.py, and imported into the application)

```
def user_function(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    if arg1 < 2.0:
        return 5.0
    if arg2 > 3.0:
        return 2.0
    return arg3
```

what i DON'T want them to be able to do is something like this (e.g. gain access to API keys, modify outside variables, make os.system() calls, etc.):

```
def user_function(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    with open("program_dump.txt", "w") as f:
        di = dict(globals())
        di.update(locals())
        json.dump(di, f)
    return 2.0
```

Is there a reasonable way to handle this without introducing a huge vulnerability space? or is my best bet to come up with some pseudo markup language and just parse that?

Ideally python 2.7 compatible

Answer (score 1):

Update: I found RestrictedPython and think this is best way to go about it - open to any other suggestions though